# Sequence Series/Summation Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

I was given the below formula to solve: 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{40}k^{2k}
$$

I'm not sure how to approach the problem considering $k$ isn't a constant to obtain any values. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have some problems with your index $i$, as it should appear in the expression.

Comment: How to use the $i$ in the subscript?

Comment: @Zhanxiong For subscripts use an underscore.

Comment: @Sky, that's not what Zhanxiong meant.

Comment: @BolzWeir Apologies. What did Zhanxiong mean?

Comment: @Sky I think he was asking about the same thing you asked about, and which I was going to ask about. The OP probably wanted a $k$ there.

Comment: Can you write a program? That's probably the easiest way.

Comment: My mistake, I meant k!

Comment: And @Kbot, yes I could - but I want to approach it manually and am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20k%5E%282k%29%20from%201%20to%2040) gives the value $\sum_{k=1}^{40} k^{2 k} = 14616284255801992521053722308218024414349383839\\254327530879300523619661334347511\\3624778023973581416780282619663230939835404121156$

I'm not sure I am any wiser for finding this.  Maybe you are expected to implement a big integer routine that can provide this answer?